# Change bar colours in combined ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below data.frame, which has 2 utilities, Electricity & Gas, each of which has a 'usage' value and a ' price' value. I've managed to plot all of these into a single plot with the 'Usage' being a geom_bar, and the 'price' being a geom_line. Would someone be able to modify my code to indicate how to change the colours for 'Electricity' and 'Gas' on the geom_bar? I can change them for the line graph, but it's been a struggle doing it for the bar chart.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18686, 18686, 18714, 18714, 
18745, 18745), class = "Date"), Utility = c("Gas", "Electricity", 
"Gas", "Electricity", "Gas", "Electricity"), usage = c(0, 0, 
125, 208, 104, 232), price = c(0, 0, 45.46, 37.82, 39.67, 43.09
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Code for plot :

```
ggplot(cost) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, fill = Utility, weight = usage), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Electricity = 'green', 
                                Gas = 'red')) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Utility),  size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Electricity = "firebrick1",
               Gas = "darkorchid1")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defined the `fill =` parameter in your `geom_bar()` you have to use `scale_fill_manual()` to change the filling of your bars. However, there is another problem with `scale_fill_hue()` as it gives you an error if you keep it in your code. Therefore, I removed `scale_fill_hue()` and changed the code as following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(cost) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, fill = Utility, weight = usage), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Utility),  size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Electricity = 'green', Gas = 'red')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Electricity = "firebrick1", Gas = "darkorchid1")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "7 day")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Well done on your fix!

Another option would be to keep your code as it is and removing the name of values in your `scale_manual` and removing `scale_fill_hue()`:

```
ggplot(cost) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, weight = usage, fill=Utility), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('green', 'red')) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Utility),  size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick1","darkorchid1")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Awesome - just another variation that worked:

```
ggplot(cost) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Date, fill = Utility, weight = usage), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Electricity = 'green', Gas = 'red')) + 
  
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Utility),  size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Electricity = "firebrick1", Gas = "darkorchid1")) +
  
   theme_minimal() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month")
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after all, needed to change 'Utility' as a factor and then add 'scale_fill_manual'.

```
ggplot(cost) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, fill = as.factor(Utility), weight = usage), alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Utility),  size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Electricity = "firebrick1",
               Gas = "darkorchid1")) + 
  scale_fill_manual("Utility", values = c("Electricity" = 'green', 
                                        "Gas" = 'red')) +
  theme_minimal() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month")
```